# C++ | Take User Input without giving a value

Tags: c++, input

I can see that the title might be a bit confusing. Basically I want the user to press enter 10 times to end the loop. But I have to actually to type something for it to count, I reckon this is because I've given 'useless' a data type of char, but what would I assign it so I can just press enter and it takes that? Thanks!

```
void mineFunc(){
//Mining Function
int durability = 10;
char useless; //Just so user can tap enter to 'mine'
cout << "Tap Enter to Mine" << endl;
do {
    cin >> useless;
    durability -= 1;
    cout << "Durability: " << durability << endl;
} while (durability > 0);
gold += 5;

}
```

Comment: Do `cin.get(useless);`

Comment: Use `std::getline()` or `std::istream`s `getline()` member function to read a line of input from `std::cin` rather than `cin >> useless`.

Comment: I agree with M.M...beat me to it. Just replace cin >> useless; with cin.get(useless); Fun little game lol.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use the IO manipulator [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) on the stream, but since it's `cin`, you might not want to leave it in that state.  And you would have to save/restore the previous state to play nice with other parts of the program.

An easier way is to just loop as follows:

```
while( cin && cin.get() != '\n' );
```

Now, if the stream fails, you want to break out of your loop.  You may want to wrap this up a bit nicer:

```
istream & wait_enter( istream & s )
{
    while( s && s.get() != '\n' );
    return s;
}
```

Then you have:

```
do {
    if( !wait_enter(cin) ) break;
    durability -= 1;
    cout << "Durability: " << durability << endl;
} while (durability > 0);
```

Because of how IO manipulators work, you could even do this (if you like that style):

```
    if( !(cin >> wait_enter) ) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline`. If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with an empty line, `getline` will return an empty line.

```
std::string dummyLine;
while ( durability > 0 && getline(std::cin, dummyLine) )
{
   --durability;
}
```

Using the above conditional in the `while` statement makes sure that if you enter `EOF`, the loop exits and does not get stuck there for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help!

I found

```
cin.get(useless);
```

to be the simplest most helpful way to solve this issue.